# How to align principal axes of 3D density map in numpy with Cartesian axes?

Tags: python, numpy, image-rotation, ndimage

I have an n x n x n numpy array that contains density values on a cubic grid. I'm trying to align the principal axes of inertia of the density map with the cartesian x,y,z axes of the grid. I have the following so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

def center_rho(rho):
    """Move density map so its center of mass aligns with the center of the grid"""
    rhocom = np.array(ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass(rho))
    gridcenter = np.array(rho.shape)/2.
    shift = gridcenter-rhocom
    rho = ndimage.interpolation.shift(rho,shift,order=1,mode='wrap')
    return rho

def inertia_tensor(rho,side):
    """Calculate the moment of inertia tensor for the given density map."""
    halfside = side/2.
    n = rho.shape[0]
    x_ = np.linspace(-halfside,halfside,n)
    x,y,z = np.meshgrid(x_,x_,x_,indexing='ij')
    Ixx = np.sum(rho*(y**2 + z**2))
    Iyy = np.sum(rho*(x**2 + z**2))
    Izz = np.sum(rho*(x**2 + y**2))
    Ixy = -np.sum(rho*x*y)
    Iyz = -np.sum(rho*y*z)
    Ixz = -np.sum(rho*x*z)
    I = np.array([[Ixx, Ixy, Ixz],
                  [Ixy, Iyy, Iyz],
                  [Ixz, Iyz, Izz]])
    return I

def principal_axes(I):
    """Calculate the principal inertia axes and order them in ascending order."""
    w,v = np.linalg.eigh(I)
    return w,v

#number of grid points along side
n = 10
#note n <= 3 produces unit eigenvectors, not sure why
#in practice, n typically between 10 and 50
np.random.seed(1)
rho = np.random.random(size=(n,n,n))
side = 1. #physical width of box, set to 1.0 for simplicity

rho = center_rho(rho)
I = inertia_tensor(rho,side)
PAw, PAv = principal_axes(I)

#print magnitude and direction of principal axes
print "Eigenvalues/eigenvectors before rotation:"
for i in range(3):
    print PAw[i], PAv[:,i]

#sanity check that I = R * D * R.T
#where R is the rotation matrix and D is the diagonalized matrix of eigenvalues
D = np.eye(3)*PAw
print np.allclose(np.dot(PAv,np.dot(D,PAv.T)),I)

#rotate rho to align principal axes with cartesian axes
newrho = ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform(rho,PAv.T,order=1,mode='wrap')

#recalculate principal axes
newI = inertia_tensor(newrho,side)
newPAw, newPAv = principal_axes(newI)

#print magnitude and direction of new principal axes
print "Eigenvalues/eigenvectors before rotation:"
for i in range(3):
    print newPAw[i], newPAv[:,i]
```

Here I'm assuming that the eigenvectors of the inertia tensor define the rotation matrix (which based on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145023/rotation-matrix-from-an-inertia-tensor) and Google results such as [this webpage](http://www.euclideanspace.com/physics/dynamics/inertia/rotation/index.htm) seems correct?) However this doesn't give me the correct result.

I expect the printed matrix to be:

```
[1 0 0]
[0 1 0]
[0 0 1]
```

(which could be wrong) but don't even get unit vectors to start with. What I get is:

```
Eigenvalues/eigenvectors before rotation:
102.405523732 [-0.05954221 -0.8616362   0.5040216 ]
103.177395578 [-0.30020273  0.49699978  0.81416801]
104.175688943 [-0.95201526 -0.10283129 -0.288258  ]
True
Eigenvalues/eigenvectors after rotation:
104.414931478 [ 0.38786    -0.90425086  0.17859172]
104.731536038 [-0.74968553 -0.19676735  0.63186566]
106.151322662 [-0.53622405 -0.37896304 -0.75422197]
```

I'm not sure if the problem is my code or my assumptions about rotating principal axes, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know this is old, but I'd like to ping this to see if someone can help out.

Comment: It turns out this does work, you just have to run it in a loop a few times. The interpolation causes issues. Once its applied 3 times or so it does give the identity matrix to within an acceptable tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/pedrogalvez/3D_Eigenvalues_rotation) is the link to the code I developed to do such alignment.

Given a set of scatter points with coordinates (x,y,z), the objective is to match the eigenvector associated to the minimum eigenvalue with the X-axis of a 3D cartesian axis and the eigenvector associated to the median eigenvalue with the Y axis from the same 3D cartesian axis.

For this purpose, I followed the following steps:

1. Translate the set of points with centroid in (xmn, ymn, zmn) to a new set of points with centroid in (0,0,0) only by doing: (x-xmn, y-ymn, z-zmn).
2. Calculate the angle THETA (rotation around z) between the xy-projection of the eigenvector associated to the minimum eigenvalue (*min_eigen*) and the  x-axis in a cartesian axis. After obtention of the resulting tetha, rotate the min_eigen the given theta so that it is contained in the xy-plane. Let's call this resulting vector: *rotz*
3. Calculate the angle PHI between *rotz* and x-axis in order to perform a rotation around the y-axis. Once the phi is obtained, a rotation is applied to *rotz* aound the  y axis. With this last rotation, the eigenvector associated to the medium eigenvector (medium_eigen) is then in the yz proyection of the cartesian axis, so we will just need to find the angle between medium_eigen and the y-axis of the cartesian axis.
4. Calculate the angle ALPHA between the medium_eigen and y-axis. Apply the rotation around the x-axis aaaand: IT'S DONE!

> NOTE: After applying steps 1,2,3 to your set of points, you have to recalculate the 3D_SVD (3D_single value decomposition) and from the resulting set of eigenvectors, then implement the 4th step with the new medium_eigen.

I really hope this helps.

The rotations are implemented by means of the rotation matrix defined here: [Rotating a Vector in 3D Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607640/rotating-a-vector-in-3d-space)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I'm actually looking for how to rotate an N x N x N array though, not a set of N points (which is an N x 3 array).  The issue primarily is interpolation I think.  I've now got some code to solve this however.