# Getting wrong values when rotating vector around axis

Tags: c++, vector, 3d

I'm trying to add rotation functions to my class, to rotate around the X, Y, Z - axis, but the output is not exactly what i expected

I made sure that my formulas are correct, they seem to be correct, but i don't know. i took them from this :  [Rotating a Vector in 3D Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607640/rotating-a-vector-in-3d-space)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <math.h>

// Vector class, to handle all the vector operations for us
// Thanks to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607640/rotating-a-vector-in-3d-space
class cVector
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    // Constructor
    cVector();
    cVector(float x1, float y1, float z1);

    // returns the vector's magnitude
    float Magnitude();

    // Normalize ( change length to 1, while keeping the same direction)
    void Normalize();


    // Rotate around the Axis
    void RotateX(float angle);
    void RotateY(float angle);
    void RotateZ(float angle);

    // TODO : Add operators for Addition & Substraction

    // Addition
    cVector operator+(cVector const& v1) const
    {
        return cVector(x + v1.x,
                        y + v1.y,
                        z + v1.z);
    }
    void operator+=(cVector const& v1)
    {
        x += v1.x;
        y += v1.y;
        z += v1.z;
    }
    // Substraction
    cVector operator-(cVector const& v1) const
    {
        return cVector(x - v1.x,
                        y - v1.y,
                        z - v1.z);
    }
    void operator-=(cVector const& v1)
    {
        x -= v1.x;
        y -= v1.y;
        z -= v1.z;
    }

    // Multiplication
    void operator*=(const float scalar)
    {
        x *= scalar;
        y *= scalar;
        z *= scalar;
    }
    cVector operator*(const float scalar) const
    {
        return cVector(x * scalar,
                        y * scalar,
                        z * scalar);
    }

    // Division
    void operator/=(const float scalar)
    {
        x /= scalar;
        y /= scalar;
        z /= scalar;
    }
    cVector operator/(const float scalar) const
    {
        return cVector(x / scalar,
                        y / scalar,
                        z / scalar);
    }
};



// Constructor
cVector::cVector()
{

}

cVector::cVector(float x1, float y1, float z1)
{
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
    z = z1;
}

// returns the vector's magnitude
float cVector::Magnitude()
{
    return sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
}

// Normalize ( change length to 1, while keeping the same direction)
void cVector::Normalize()
{
    float flMagnitude = Magnitude();

    // We devide the coordinates by the magnitude
    x /= flMagnitude;
    y /= flMagnitude;
    z /= flMagnitude;
}

// Rotate around the Axis
void cVector::RotateX(float angle)
{
    y = y * cos(angle) - z * sin(angle);
    z = y * sin(angle) + z * cos(angle);
}

void cVector::RotateY(float angle)
{
    x = (x * cos(angle)) + (z * sin(angle));
    z = (-x * sin(angle)) + (z * cos(angle));
}

void cVector::RotateZ(float angle)
{
    x = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle);
    y = x * sin(angle) + y * cos(angle);
}

void PrintVector(cVector vec)
{
    cout << "X : " << vec.x << " Y : " << vec.y << " Z : " << vec.z << endl;
}

// TODO : Add operators for Addition & Substraction
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;



    cVector vec(10, 0, 0);

    vec.RotateZ(1.57f);

    PrintVector(vec);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the method to keep the same magnitude of the vector, and return ( 0, 10, 0) since i'm rotating by pi/2 , but that's not what i'm getting. apparently if i rotate by pi, i get a good result, but other than that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your Rotation for example in RotateZ you should save the x in some temporary because if you modify it & then try to use it for the y it's obviously gonna cause you an error, ie you should do something like this

```
void cVector::RotateZ(float angle)
{
    float temp = x;
    x = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle);
    y = temp * sin(angle) + y * cos(angle);
}
```

Second the value of pi you are given is way too over-rounded so the values are false

you can do something like for you pi value

```
const float Pi = 3.1415926535;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I completely missed that.