# Rotating vector by an angle and by given direction vector of the axis and there is a point of the axis. (3 dimensions)

Tags: c#, math, vector, linear-algebra

1. The 3D coordinates of the vector.
2. The rotation angle in radians.
3. The 3D coordinates of a point of the axis.
4. The 3D coordinates of the direction vector of the axis.

The length of the direction vector is greater than 1e-8.

how I should rotate input vector?

First of all, I need to move my coordinate system into another start point?
I don't understand how I should rotate my vector around a direction one.
And then.. I should rotate at first around x axis, then y, and then z?

Comment: [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607640/rotating-a-vector-in-3d-space) might help you

Answer (score 0):

There is effective approach - using [Rodrigues formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_rotation_formula)

To rotate vector **V** about axis with unit direction vector **k** by angle `theta`:

```
Vrot = V * cos(theta) + (k x v) * sin(theta) + k * (k.dot.v) * (1 - cos(theta))
```